# Get value automatically from dropdown in another input field

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a selection dropdown to get mail from the user in different department of my company.
I want,when the user select department name from the drop down ,the mail adress of the department will set automatically in next input field.

```
<select class="form-control" id="mail_type" name="email_to" onChange="getMailtype(this.value)" required>
  <option value="support@mail.com" selected>Support</option>
  <option value="bill@mail.com">Billing</option>
  <option value="sales@mail.com">Sales</option>
 </select>

 <span id="mail_info">
 <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" value="support@mail.com" readonly>
  </span>
```

so,here I select an option and email input field will get the value automatically using js

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the `input` and set the value of the `select`

```js
function getMailtype(value) {
  document.querySelector("#mail_info input").value = value;
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" id="mail_type" name="email_to" onChange="getMailtype(this.value)" required>
  <option value="support@mail.com" selected>Support</option>
  <option value="bill@mail.com">Billing</option>
  <option value="sales@mail.com">Sales</option>
</select>

<span id="mail_info">
 <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" value="support@mail.com" readonly>
  </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const getMailtype = (target) => {
  $("#mail_info > input[name='email'")[0].value = target.value;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="mail_type" name="email_to" onChange="getMailtype(this)" required>
  <option value="support@mail.com" selected>Support</option>
  <option value="bill@mail.com">Billing</option>
  <option value="sales@mail.com">Sales</option>
</select>

<span id="mail_info">
 <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" value="support@mail.com" readonly>
  </span>
```